# Is it true that the square of an even integer is always a multiple of 4?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Just out of curiosity. I'm new to number theory. If it's true, please show a proof. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see there should be any question there, unless what you said has unusual definition.

Comment: What is your definition of "even"? What about "square"? What about "multiple"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n$ be an even integer. Then $n = 2k$ for some integer $k$. Then
$$n^2 = (2k)^2 = 4k^2$$
showing $n^2$ is a multiple of $4$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if x is even then $x=2n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so $x^2=4(n^2)$.

Comment: Ok I see, makes sense now. Thanks for helping me wrap my head around it!